# Access C++/CX method from standard C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I'm trying to solve one little problem. I have a library written in standard C++ and new application for Windows Phone 8 thats using C++/CX. I can instantiate old library objects and call old methods from C++/CX, but I also need to access to new C++/CX methods from old C++.

Problem is that new app's class is using "*ref class Renderer sealed*" and I'm not to able pass that pointer and include that file to old c++ code.
I need to do something like that:

application's main object written in C++/CX

```
void function(){
  Renderer^ m_renderer = ref new Renderer();
  MyOldLib * m_lib = new MyOldLib();
  m_lib->setLink(m_renderer); // <-- I cannot pass parameter becouse ordinary reference is not allowed
}
```

old library written in standard C++

```
#include "Renderer.h" // <-- I cannot include becouse Renderer.h needs /ZW parameter
void MyOldLib::setLink(Renderer& renderer){
   m_renderer = renderer;
}
```

Thank you for your help

*update: extended pseudocode*

Comment: Well, zero odds that the C++ code knows anything about your Renderer class.  What does the actual declaration of setLink() look like?

Comment: If you cannot convert your library to C++/CX, you can look at WRL as alternative to operate on Windows Runtime objects. Look at [WRL integration (C++/CX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699869.aspx) to get started.

Comment: Nowadays consider Kenny Kerr's C++/WinRT as an alternative to either C++/CX above or as the way to interwork with the C++/CX code via standard C++.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis